# Header in gmail for thread hinting

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to aid gmail in making threads?  We are currently using same Subjects to do this, but that really uglyfies the subject a lot.

Comment: Need details.  If you ask me, removing the "Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: ..." stuff prettifies the subjects quite a bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of mail headers that other mail clients use to help threading - not sure if gmail supports them.  The first is the standard RFC-822 "`In-Reply-To: <messageid>`", and the second is the non-standard (stolen from Usenet) "`References: <messageid>,<messageid>,...`".

Comment: Confirmed by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430866/gmail-threading-imap-and-ruby