# How to make GMail continue a conversation?

Tags: gmail

When providing **the same subject line** doesn't work?

I'd like to send 2 emails and make them appear in one conversation. Sadly, the second one always starts a new conversation. How to avoid this?

Both mails are sent directly to `my.address@gmail.com`

Both have almost the same headers and the same UTF-8 encoded subjects:

```
Delivered-To: my.account@gmail.com
Received: by ...
Return-Path: ...
Received: ...
Received-SPF: pass ...
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass ...
Received: from mm_www by ...
To: my.account@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?...=?=
From: notification@my.domain
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Mailer: PHP
Message-Id: ... (Different for both messages. Should I add my own id?)
Date: ...
```

Any clues?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question.

Comment: I disagree, Chris.  Asking about how to work with a protocol most certainly is programming related, especially one like this.

Comment: It depends; he might want to write a program to send messages to a Gmail account and have them appear in the same conversation.  It's kind of a stretch, but I can definitely see wanting to do this programmatically in some cases.

Comment: What language are you doing this in Mati?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372449/header-in-gmail-for-thread-hinting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the message ID is what's important here.  The client uses it to determine flow.

Comment: No, Message-ID doesn't have anything to do with it, except when you make the second message you should put the first one's Message-ID in the "In-Reply-To" header.

Comment: My mistake, I read a quick summary of a document and got the wrong impression.  This should be unaccepted.

Comment: @CodyBrocious You may want to update your answer. Probably not everyone reads the comments :P