# gmail Conversation via smtp

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

how can i send an email as a part of a gmail-conversation via smtp?
Taking the same subject doesnt work...

tell me if you need more infos...
thanks in advance!

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("@googlemail.com");
        mail.To.Add("@.com");
        mail.Subject = "(Somee.com notification) New order confirmation";
        mail.Body = "(Somee.com notification) New order confirmation";

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use the following:

```
mail.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", <messageid>);
```

The message id you should be able to get from the previous email's headers.  Just look for "Message-Id".

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372449/header-in-gmail-for-thread-hinting) gives a few more headers you may want to add to try help threading in other clients.  It seems maybe gmail is now using these, too.

Comment: To be entirely clear. That `<messagid> ` looks like this `<DBH8Es-ZvvbnxE_lfkdsnsdfifKLJH78gJHGKJgIUGHJnL=xF2t@mail.gmail.com>`